# Setting the default page using quintagroup.transmogrifier generic setup import doesn't work with dexterity

Tags: plone, dexterity, transmogrifier

We're using a quintagroup.transmogrifier content import profile to load content for our automated tests (very useful).  Setting the default page doesn't seem to work.

The docs suggest quintagroup.transmogrifier supports setting default pages but not whether it does for generic set-up import steps.  I eventually figured out you need to add a properties.xml file into the folder of the folderish item with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<properties>
    <property name="default_page" type="string">
        index
    </property>
</properties>
```

where index is replaced by the id of the default page and also in your import.cfg you need

```
[transmogrifier]
pipeline =
    reader
    …
    propertiesimporter

[reader]
…
.properties.xml = propertymanager

[propertiesimporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.propertiesimporter
```

However this doesn't work.  We're running Plone 4.1rc3 + Dexterity 1.0 and presumably it's not compatible with Dexterity.  I've tracked down the bit of code in quintagroup.transmogrifier.propertymanager.PropertiesImporterSection where it is falling down:

```python
        path = item[pathkey]
        obj = self.context.unrestrictedTraverse(path, None)
```

Here path is a unicode string and unrestrictedTraverse returns None.  If you use a byte string then it returns the correct object.  Is this an incompatibility with Dexterity or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug you'll need to report with the authors of the quintagroup.transmogrifier package. Paths must always be ASCII bytestrings, not Unicode objects. All sections in collective.transmogrifier (the underlying engine that quintagroup.transmogrifier uses) encode paths to ASCII.

Here is a code snippet from [collective.transmogrifier.sections.constructor](http://dev.plone.org/collective/browser/collective.transmogrifier/trunk/src/collective/transmogrifier/sections/constructor.py#L41) for example:

```py
     type_, path = item[typekey], item[pathkey]

     fti = self.ttool.getTypeInfo(type_)
     if fti is None:                           # not an existing type
         yield item; continue

     path = path.encode('ASCII')
     elems = path.strip('/').rsplit('/', 1)
     container, id = (len(elems) == 1 and ('', elems[0]) or elems)
     context = self.context.unrestrictedTraverse(container, None)
```

Report it to the [dedicated issue tracker on Plone.org](http://plone.org/products/quintagroup.transmogrifier/issues) so the authors can fix it for you.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice.  I've raised an issue http://plone.org/products/quintagroup.transmogrifier/issues/3/view and for the time being am setting the default page in my test set-up methods

Comment: @martijn-pieters, there is another blueprint called  'plone.app.transmogrifier.urlnormalizer' which could be added to the pipeline to fix the ascii issues. I did have issues if the path included a folder.

Comment: @pigeonflight: indeed, using the URL normalizer section would help clean up paths in this case. But it would still be a work-around; the quintagroup code should not assume the path is a plain string.